# Explicit computations of Serre duality for elliptic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, duality, serre-duality

I have an elliptic curve $E$ defined over a ring $R$, I want to compute the pairing

$$
H^1(E,\mathcal{O}_E)\times H^0(E, \Omega_E^1){\rightarrow}R.
$$

Clearly we have that $H^0(E, \Omega_E^1)=R \langle w_{can} \rangle$
and I see that $
H^1(E,\mathcal{O}_E)$ could be seen as

$$
\Gamma(E,\mathcal{O}_E(P)/\mathcal{O}_E)=R \left \langle \frac{y}{x} \right \rangle
$$

where $x$ has a pole in $P$ with order $2$ and $y$ has a pole at $P$ with order $3$ (with $1,x$ free generators of $\mathcal{O}_E(2P)$ and $1,x,y$ free generators of $\mathcal{O}_E(3P)$. How can I for example compute the product

$$
 \langle 1,w_{can} \rangle \qquad \text{or}\qquad  \langle y/x, w_{can} \rangle  \qquad \text{or}\qquad \langle x, w_{can}\otimes w_{can} \rangle ?
$$

For me could be usefull also to understand the case where $R$ is the field of complex number $\mathbb{C}$. (In order to create some intuition).

I think that the point is to understand the so called trace isomorphism

$$
tr: H^1(E, \Omega_E^1) \rightarrow R
$$
and compute
$$
tr([w_{can}]);\qquad \text{or}\qquad  tr( [ y/x w_{can} ] )  \qquad \text{or}\qquad (tr\otimes tr) ( [x w_{can}\otimes w_{can}]).
$$

Thank you!